# Odoo / OpenERP Integrity Error on delete order_line

Tags: odoo, integrity

I use delegation to inherit fields from sale_order in a custom module:

```
class EXAMPLE(osv.osv):
_name = 'EXAMPLECLASS'

_inherits = {
    'sale.order': 'sale_order_id'}
```

I'm using the standard view for sale_order. Everything works fine, I can add and update order_lines within the sale_order. However, when I try to delete an order_line from the sale_order I get the following error:

```
Integrity Error
The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set
[object with reference: order_id - order.id]
```

What am I missing? I think it has something to do with the fact that '_inherits' only inherits fields and not methods.

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually this error is when that object has other object asociated that doesnt let you delete it (for example when u do a purchase order you cant delete the purchase if its validated because u first need to delete the documents asociated like the stock picking or invoice, and after that you cant delete the purchase order).
What did you change in your code when you inherited it?

Comment: For testing purposes I did not make any changes to the code. I could not find any dependencies. I did managed to work around the problem though: I also inherited from sale.order.line and changed the 'required' attribute of 'order_id' to 'False' and instead put this constraint in the view_definition. This seems to solve it. Thank you for your help.